# How much other information can be learned from this geocoordinate post?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

At 5:30 a.m. CDT there was a post on reddit allegedly from Omegle with geocoordinates of a body of a girl who has been missing 5 months.

Here is the imgur link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljwic.png

Here is the link to the reddit post.
http://www.reddit.com/r/creepy/comments/2cod1q/an_anonymous_person_just_confessed_the_murder_of/

Can this community assist in identifying the person who made this post? Can you assist in verifying whether there is a body there?

If you cannot, can you pass this inquiry along to other tech people who will?

For Stack Exchange purposes, how much  information can be learned from this small amount of data?

Comment: Latitude and longitude provide geographic location. It does not provide personally identifiable information -- imagine the number of people who could be identified as having been in Times Square at some point, for example.

Comment: I think you're being downvoted because this question fringes on being too broad/slightly off topic. I also don't understand your tags "geoserver" or "geotiff". Maybe if you focus your question about crime analysis, or how GIS can aid in a criminal investigation you may receive better responses.

Comment: I read the two links, This is not appropriate for Stack Exchange .. Some of the commentary on one of the links is definitely not appropriate for a professional forum ..

Comment: inappropriate for GIS stackexchange

Comment: I know virtually nothing about GIS except that this Topic exists. I had originally included 3 posts but was told I did not have enough points to do so. I am well aware that reddit has inappropriate posts but wanted to show the source of the information as I saw it especially because I am so ill-informed (no irony there). My question to the experts here was whether  any thing  like metadata could be gleaned from the evidence presented.Please edit the question to reach the substance of my query.  Thanks.

Comment: I would edit your post and links to be more about crime analysis and how GIS can be used. You might also want to look into how Omegle stores it's data, I'm sure they log ips. If my answer isn't sufficient enough for you, I'd suggest editing your question further.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I don't feel I have enough expertise to re-frame the question to meet StackExchange's requirements. I have no idea how to look into how Omegle stores its data. I am a layman without much technical expertise at all. That is one reason I asked the question here. While I truly appreciate your response my nose is feeling somewhat out of joint by the site's response in general. I am not going to pursue it further.

Answer (score 2):

**I think this is best left up to the authorities.**

However, from a GIS perspective, a location is given. That's about it. From a crime analysis perspective, if the technology is available (more than certainly it is) the police could track cellphone GPS locations that were in that area at the time.  As another reddit user posted they could potentially track people who 'googled' those specific coordinates before the post was made.

From a GIS perspective, if additional forensic evidence was provided they could do a buffer analysis from that point to determine how far someone would have driven in order to dump the body/how far away they are given a specific time frame.
There's something called [Geoprofiling](http://www.gislounge.com/crime-mapping-and-analysis/) which is based on the principal that:

> that criminals tend to commit acts of crimes within a comfort zone located near but not too close to their residence.

If there are additional forensic details like say mud, spores, pollen, trees that could also narrow the scope. You could use GIS to overlay where specific spores are found vs where the body is to determine where she was murdered/where she has been.

Additional video footage from stores, dash cams, home security etc could also be used as another type of 'tracker'. If they can determine a time frame, they could pull this footage and perhaps provide information about a specific vehicle used and direction traveled, which could then be input into a GIS.

I'm sure someone with more experience can answer this question, I watch a lot of crime shows so those are just some ideas off the top of my head.